# How is PEOS different from Monero and other privacy coins?

Tags: monero

PEOS is supposedly another privacy coin, but built using EOS tech. How is it different? And how is it going to implement monero tech combine with EOS tech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEOS has not implemented anonymity features yet (ring signatures, zk-snarks, etc...)

So right now, the difference is PEOS is not anonymous.

Comment: Monero is not anonymous just because from ring signatures, but a mix of other tech aswell.

Comment: You are correct, it is a combination of other tech. Peos has only released their intention to implement ring signatures, haven't heard them mention zk-snarks or any of the other technologies that go into anonymity coins. I think the important thing to know though, is that it is not anonymous now and they haven't released full implementation details.

Comment: Where in the paper they state they are implementing ring signatures?

Comment: From their home page:
"Leveraging ring signatures, ring confidential transactions and stealth addresses pEOS is truly private. It combines Monero's technology with EOS' performance."
https://peos.one/